# Why the cropped rectangle is not fitting the pictureBox sizemode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my program i did that on the listBox i have items when i select an item i see a screenshot image in the picturebox on the right. Then i can draw a rectangle on the pictureBox and with a button click i can crop the rectangle. The problem is that i need to make the pictureBox in the form1 designer SizeMode proprty to be zoom or stretch image if not when i select an item i see the screenshot in pictureBox too large. Only if it's zoom or stretch i see it good. But then when  i crop the rectangle it's not fitting and i need the pictureBox sizemode to be Normal. How can i fix it ?

This is my form1 code:

[Form1.cs](http://pastebin.com/RasHgAXZ)

This is how i select and item and display the image of it:

```
private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
            selectedIndex = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
            for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rectangles[i] != RectClone)
                {
                    ClearGraphics = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearGraphics = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

And this is the paint event:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
            {
                {
                    if (ClearGraphics == false)
                    {

                            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] != Rectangle.Empty)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex]);
                            }




                    }
                    if (cropRect == true)
                    {
                        if (recttest.Width > 10 && recttest.Height > 10)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBoxSnap.Image, new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height), rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```

The drawimage line draw the cropped rectangle.

The problem is that if SizeMode set to Normal i see good the cropped rectangle but then the screenshot/image when i select an item dosent fit the pictureBox too large. And if i change the sizemode to zoom i see the selected item image good but the cropped image is not fitting.

**EDITED:**

When it set to Normal i see the cropped image in the rectangle good but then the screenshot of a selected item look like zoom in very big/wide in the pictureBox. And if it set to zoom i see the image of a item good but then the rectangle i draw i see the cropped image inside not what i marked with the rectangle but more like the image 0,0 area part.

This is a link with 4 images i took and explained each one what SizeMode the pictureBox is and what is the problem. I can't upload here images so i did an album in my [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/people/Shelly-Rods/100005399954689)

Comment: When it set to Normal i see the cropped image in the rectangle good but then the screenshot of a selected item look like zoom in very big/wide in the pictureBox. And if it set to zoom i see the image of a item good but then the rectangle i draw i see the cropped image inside not what i marked with the rectangle but more like the image 0,0 area part.

Comment: This is a link with 4 images i took and explained each one what SizeMode the pictureBox is and what is the problem. I can't upload here images so i did an album in my facebook: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100005399954689&sk=photos&collection_token=100005399954689%3A2305272732%3A69&set=a.265235640333099.1073741825.100005399954689&type=3&uploaded=4

Comment: You are drawing the image on `PictureBox` instead of assigning the image to the `Image` property of that `PrictureBox`.

Comment: Shell you mean for example to set the pictureBox to zoom mode and then assign the rectangle i draw to the pictureBox image property instead drawing it ?

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawImage` method will draw the image on particular area  where the `SizeMode` property works for assigned image in `Image` property. the `SizeMode` property will allow you to display that image which you have set in the `Image` property will be resized to its appropriate size and display it on that `PictureBox`.

Comment: If you want to draw that image using `e.Graphics.DrawImage` with the fit to the picturebox size then you have to resize that image first.

Comment: Shell i don't want that the cropped rectangle to fit to the pictureBox size i want that the part i cropped from the original image will be fit into the rectangle. For example i drawed on the pictureBox rectangle at 55,100 now i want that this part of image i marked with the rectangle to stay in the rectangle and all the rest to remove. So in the end the rectangle will stay at 55,100 with the part of the original image i drawed it on. The problem is with the size mode. I showed it on my facebook album with 4 images. The rectangle size is fine the part of the image i cropped is not fine.

Comment: To make it in the pictureBox size it's not a problem i did it before. Thep roblem is to fit the cropped area rectangle to the rectangle it self. I crop some area of the image and it show me in the rectangle another part of the image.

Comment: I think u forgot this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25396377/3761928). there is always another way but, which is the best that is more important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....
....
if (cropRect == true){
    if (recttest.Width > 10 && recttest.Height > 10){
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, pictureBoxSnap.Width, rect.Y);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Height);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y, pictureBoxSnap.Width - rect.X - rect.Width, rect.Height);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, rect.Y + rect.Height, pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height - rect.Y - rect.Height);
     }
}
```

or better

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
    Point pnt;

    ....
    ....
    if (cropRect == true){
        if (recttest.Width > 10 && recttest.Height > 10){
            pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);

            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + rect.X, pnt.Y + rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Y, New Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
        }
    }
```

valter

Comment: @ShellyRods See another way.